# How to log same message with syslog()?

Tags: c, repeat, syslog

I'm trying to use `syslog.h` libraries to log message in my projects. I noticed that if I try to log the same message, in `/var/log/syslog` it appears only one time; here is my example code and setting:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //Initialize syslog
  setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
  openlog("example_process", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_USER);

  while(main_loop == LOOP_CONTINUE)
    {
       syslog(LOG_ERR, "Data Logged!\n");
       sleep(60);
    }

  closelog();
}
```

and this is the result:

```
Feb 11 23:27:19 andrea-Aspire-5745G example_process[17332]: Data Logged!
andrea@andrea-Aspire-5745G:~$
```

But if I change the code in

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //Initialize syslog
  setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
  openlog("example_process", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_USER);

  while(main_loop == LOOP_CONTINUE)
    {
       syslog(LOG_ERR, "Data Logged!\n");
       syslog(LOG_ERR, "Data Logged2!\n");
       sleep(60);
    }

  closelog();
}
```

It writes every reiteration:

```
Feb 11 17:43:06 andrea-Aspire-5745G example_process[7645]: Data Logged!
Feb 11 17:43:06 andrea-Aspire-5745G example_process[7645]: Data Logged2!
Feb 11 17:43:10 andrea-Aspire-5745G example_process[7645]: Data Logged!
Feb 11 17:43:10 andrea-Aspire-5745G example_process[7645]: Data Logged2!
Feb 11 17:43:13 andrea-Aspire-5745G example_process[7645]: Data Logged!
Feb 11 17:43:13 andrea-Aspire-5745G example_process[7645]: Data Logged2!
```

I understand that log every the same message is not a good idea, but here is my question:

Is there a method or an option to make it possible?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26337/suppress-duplicate-messages-in-rsyslog and http://serverfault.com/questions/30303/is-there-a-way-to-remove-last-message-repeated-x-times-from-logs

Comment: After all the repetitions are done, you'll see a message that says "Last message repeated N times"

Comment: *I* would worry more about why the `sleep(60)` is not spacing the messages to be 60 seconds apart.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm very sorry but i have copied from the wrong part of log file.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the solution.